# ASP.Net Routing with Web Forms and SSL Page Not Found

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, routes, url-rewriting

I have an ASP.NET 4 Web Forms application that I am attempting to deploy to a production server (Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6.0).

I have already deployed this application to a test server with the same setup and configuration successfully and all the routing worked great on the test server.

I am now getting 404's on all routes on the production server.  The only difference between the test and production servers is that the production server uses SSL which is handled at the load balancer level.

I am able to access the pages without the "routed" urls (manually entering in the .aspx extentions, etc).

Has anyone run into a similar issue? Is routing not supported in this type of environment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This actually started working magically on its own...

Here is my take on what may have happened:

An admin originally created the website in IIS as an ASP.NET 2.0 application.  Not wanting to bring down other sites that are hosted on the server, I changed the framework version by running the aspnet_regiis command that does not restart the W3SVC service.

This should require an app pool recycle for the application you are changing the framework for but wont interfere with the other applications hosted on the server.  I performed the recycle, but it still did not work.

After a while I tried hitting the URLs again, and all worked.  My only guess is that possibly an IISReset occurred causing it to work in that period of time.